# Здравствуйте. Как преобразовать набор чисел ,получений из формулы, в вектор или массив?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
int main () {
int rows = 2, cols = 20;
int a, b;
int **array = new int* [rows]; 
for ( int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
   array[i] = new int[cols];
}
std::cout << "Введіть ліву границю діапазону: \n";
std::cin >> a;
std::cout << "Введіть праву границю діапазону: \n";
std::cin >> b;
for (int i = 0; i< rows; i++){
for (int j=0; j<cols; j++){
    array[i][j] = rand()%(b-a+1)+a;;
    std::cout << array[i][j] << "\t";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
}

 int maxsum=2*a - 1;
for (int i = 0; i< 2; i++){
for (int j=0; j < 19  ; j++) 
 maxsum = std::max(maxsum, array[i][j]+ array[i][j+1]);
 std::cout << "\n Максимальна сума: " << maxsum;

}

for (int i=0; i< rows; i++){
delete [] array[i];
}
delete[] array;

}
```

Comment: Не очень понятно, что нужно сделать.

Comment: Вы внятно опишите поставленную задачу, а то получается "поди туда — не знаю куда"...

Comment: Выводится 40 раз, потому что вы его 40 раз выводите: внутри третьего цикла переменные `i` и `j` не изменяются, соответственно вы рассчитываете и выводите сумму одних и тех же элементов массива `array`. Как это исправить? Нужно знать исходное условие задачи...

Comment: изменила условие,  посмотрите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для поиска максимума среди сумм пар массив вам не нужен.

```
int maxsum = 2*a - 1;
for (int i = 0; i< 2; i++){
   for (int j=0; j<   19  ; j++)  //обратите внимание на диапазон
     maxsum = std::max(maxsum, array[i][j]+ array[i][j+1]);
```

Comment: а куда нужно вставить этот фрагмент кода? В терминале выводит "Максимальне значення суми: 1814 
Максимальне значення суми: 16
Максимальне значення суми: 1814 
Максимальне значення суми: 16" и на месте 14 каждый раз разные числа

Comment: После заполнения рандомом вместо всего остального (от int k 40) вставляете этот кусок и после него один раз выводите cout maxsum

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь! вы не знаете, почему может выводится 2 максимальные суммы(16 и 18 например)?

Comment: Наверное, потому что вы так сделали. Отредактируйте вопрос, добавив текущий код

Comment: добавила, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Фигурную скобку переставьте до std cout, чтобы ввод был после всех циклов или вообще их скобки удалите, т.к. внутри цикла один оператор

Comment: спасибо вам большое